# Non Blocking retry implementing using kafka stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are trying to implement kafka retry using application.yaml configuration which is working as expected. However it's blocking queue implementation any way we can implement it using non blocking retry topic using application yaml configurations only.

We have tried to implement it using application yaml config which is working in blocking queue.

```
handleTestEvent-in-0:
          group: test-topic-group
          destination: ${TEST_EVENT_TOPIC}
         consumer:
           maxAttempts: 5
           backOffInitialInterval: 60000
           backOffMaxInterval: 1000000
           backOffMultiplier: 2.0
           defaultRetryable: false
           retryable-exceptions:
             java.lang.RuntimeException: true
```